# Insert directive template after another element when this one is clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a custom directive.
This is what I have:

```
<button myDirective>Click Me</button>
```

My directive looks like this:

```
return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  controller: 'Controller',
  replace: false,
  template: '<h3>Test</h3>', // actually more complex
  link: function( $scope, $element, $attrs ) {
    $element.on( 'click', function() {
      // code, that shows the template
    });
  }
};
```

Result is:

```
<button myDirective>Click Me
  <h3>Test</h3>
</button>
```

But i want to have something like this:

```
<button myDirective>Click Me</button>
<h3>Test</h3> <!-- just shown after button is clicked -->
```

After the button  is clicked the template should be shown after the button.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rendering the button in directive template.
Here's an example snippet:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('expander', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: true,
      template: '<div><button ng-click="showContent=true">{{buttonText}}</button><h3 ng-show="showContent">Test</h3></div>',
      link: function( $scope, $element, $attrs ) {
        $scope.buttonText = $attrs.text;
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <expander text="Press me"></expander>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jqLite's `.after()` to append the content after any element the directive is attached to, then hide and show the content on click.

### View:

```
<button my-directive>Click Me!</button>
```

### Directive:

```
return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  scope: {
    time: '='
  },
  link: function($scope, $element){
    var afterStuff = angular.element('<h3 style="display:none;">Test</h3>');

    $element.after(afterStuff);
    //full jquery version
    $element.on('click', function(){
      afterStuff.toggle();
    });
  }
}
```

JSBin: https://jsbin.com/xuwuhu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: thats not possible because the directive has to be linked to a button an triggered by that button. Or it can be ANY element.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your specific use case from your description.  You can still access the button when it is a child of your directive.

Comment: Perhaps transclude would be better then: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-wraps-other-elements

Comment: The thing is, that the content of the directive is shown in the DOM, when any element (in this case a button) with the attribute is clicked.

Comment: So the content you want to show already exists on the page, and you want the directive to hide and show that particular element?  Or should the directive add the content for each directive?

Comment: Here's a bin that appends the content after the button and then toggles the visibility when the button is clicked: https://jsbin.com/xuwuhu/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngif or ngshow to display you content after lifting a flag in your button handler.